# Hoverable button over hoverablecard?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a card which is hoverable and I'd like a button on the card which is also hoverable, is that possible?

I have tried;

```
<div class="card border-0" style="width: 100%;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="image here" alt="Card image">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <div class="bottom text-light text-left">
            <h4>{{ ucwords(trans($group->group_title)) }}</h4>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Join the group"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></button>
    </div>
    <a href="{{ route('groups.show',$group->id)}}" class="stretched-link"></a>
</div>
```

But the `btn btn-light btn-circle` isn't hoverable and doesn't show tool tip?

I have tried adding `style="z-index:2"` to the button but no joy.

```
<div class="card border-0" style="width: 100%;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="image" alt="Card image">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <div class="bottom text-light text-left">
            <h4>{{ ucwords(trans($group->group_title)) }}</h4>
            <br>
            <h5>1,235 members</h5>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-circle" style="z-index:2" data-join-group="terms" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Join the group"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></button>
    </div>
    <a href="{{ route('groups.show',$group->id)}}" class="stretched-link"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from your question that you want to display `tooltip` on both button and card, if this correct, here is the code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card border-0" style="width: 100%;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Card tooltip">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="image here" alt="Card image">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <div class="bottom text-light text-left">
            <h4>Some Text</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Join the group"><i class="fa fa-star"></i>Button</button>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="stretched-link"></a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```